# Чи є вираз "все включено" нормативним в українській мові?

Tags: фразеологізми, запозичені-слова

З [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE):

> Все включено (англ. All-inclusive resort) — система готельного
>   обслуговування, за якої харчування та алкогольні напої включені у
>   вартість проживання.

Однак, у самій статті немає жодних посилань на джерела. Я підозрюю, що цей вираз є калькою з російської.

Чи це так? І чи є альтернативні варіанти, що мають те ж значення?

Comment: Тоді вже калькою з англійської - all included (може, через російську). До речі, калька, навіть з російської — це нормальний спосіб словотворення. На мою думку, "все включено" вже прижилося, і навіть якщо ви знайдете якийсь "більш автентичний" варіант, у нього мало шансів замінити вираз, що вже став сталим.

Comment: Погоджуюсь, що запозичення - це нормальний процес і що цей вираз "знайшов своє місце під українським сонцем" :). Але раптом в когось будуть якісь оригінальні ідеї чи цікаві факти. Відповідь "так, це запозичення" також приймається, при достатній аргументації.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Я не бачу причин, за якими «все включено» може бути не нормативним. Може він неоптимальний, але у СУМ-20:

- > [ВКЛЮ́ЧЕНИЙ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15052&page=493). Дієпр. пас. до включи́ти.
- > [ВКЛЮЧА́ТИ, ВКЛЮЧИ́ТИ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15050&page=492). 2. Уводити до складу, приєднувати до кого-, чого-небудь.
- Отже **все включено** [до комплекту/переліку передоплачених послуг] — все введено/приєднано до комплекту/переліку передоплачених послуг.

---

Що десь згадуються:

- **Все враховано**:

  - [вживається на hotels.com](//www.google.com/search?num=100&q=%22%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%22+site:ua.hotels.com).
- **Повний пансіон**.

  [«Повний пансіон» у СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pansion).

  В сучасних готелях повний пансіон і «все включено» різняться ([1](http://tourlib.net/books_ukr/pucentejlo118.htm), [2](http://tursvit.info/shho-take-povnyj-pansion-u-goteli/), [3](https://olympica.com.ua/495420-povnijj-pansion-shho-ce.html)):

  - повний пансіон — це коли включені сніданок, обід і вечеря;
  - «все включено» може додатково включати в себе закуски і напої між основними прийомани їжі, можливо, навіть уночі, можливо, додаткові розваги й інше.

  Проте я б не розглядав повний пансіон і «все включено» як поняття, що не перетинаються. Радше «повний пансіон» є гіперонімом до «все включено» (адже «все включено» має на увазі, як мінімум, повний пансіон). Тим більше, що за тими ж посиланнями вище сказано, що люди часто плутають ці поняття і що значення «все включено» різниться від готелю до готелю. Тобто «повний пансіон» — більш надійний (із фіксованим значенням) термін, але в загальному випадку менш вимогливий, ніж «все включено».
- **Повне утримання**.

  Це радше не термін, а просто характеристика.

  [Використання словосполучення «повне утримання» у СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pansion).

<sub>Пропозиції без аргументації: все [введено](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048804298488671)/[вклю**чн**о](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048871115148656)/[вміщено/внесено/впроваджено](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048804298488671)/[входить](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048680058501095)/[додано/долучено](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048804298488671)/[завбачено](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048681465167621)/[заведено](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048804298488671)/[залучено](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1542966405970726/permalink/1689299728004059/?comment_id=1689723654628333)/[занесено/записано](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048804298488671)/оплачено/[охоплено](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048804298488671)/[передбачено](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048837321818702)/передоплачено/[продумано](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048681041834330),
[всі виго́ди](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048795381822896),
[повний сервіс](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1048677688501332/?comment_id=1048837321818702).</sub>